# Prevent objects to be created if it has created more than 10+ in a certain amount of time?

Tags: django

If I have a Entry object in Django. How could I limit the amount of Entries been created in 10 minutes or so?

The scenario is if a user tries to create 10+ posts under a certain period it will give a warning saying that you cannot create more posts bla bla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    content = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

num_recent_posts = user.post_set.filter(
    date_created__gte=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10),
).count()

if num_recent_posts > 10:
    ...
```